# vertically centring not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, absolute

I have the following code which creates an 'img-cell'div  which is empty with a height and background-image. And a 'text-cell' div underneath. (both 100% width) (php code removed, it doesn't affect the layout)

HTML

```
<article>
 <div class="img-cell">
 </div>

  <div class="text-cell">
   <div class="extra-css" >
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h3>Category</h3>
   </div>
 </div>  
</article>
```

CSS

```
 article {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
 }

.img-cell { 
  position: relative;
  height: 375px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

 .text-cell {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   padding: 15px 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   display:table;
 }
```

this puts the 'text-cell' div vertically centred over 'image-cell' div. It only works in Safari, but not in Firefox or the other browsers. It has to do with display:table. I don't want to use tables but I can't figure out how how to vertically center 'text-cell'

EDIT - I have the 'text-cell' position:relative on mobile size screens so it goes below the 'img-cell' div

Comment: i tried that since I figured it was the easiest answer but it doesn't work

Comment: It should be - vertical-align:middle;.

Comment: because you given `top:0` to `text-cell`. Check http://jsfiddle.net/1L7yora9/1/

Comment: your fiddle doesn't center properly. In all the forums I have checked, it needs both top: 0; and bottom:0; with display:table. It just doesn't work with firefox

Comment: It is centring the top of the div, not centring the div like it does with display:table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other approach to try to solve your issue, same HTML but slightly different CSS:

```
 article {
   position: relative;
 }

.img-cell {
  height: 375px; 
}

 .text-cell {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsbin.com/tumofitera/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: My concern is putting a fixed height on text-cell. It's a responsive site so I don't have all the control over content. I've mentioned in another comment that I used top:30% to fake looking centred, but when text starts taking up 2+ lines it no longer looks centred

Comment: You don't have to put a fixed height on the text-cell. It should sort itself out automagically without it :)

Comment: It works in firefox etc, but it  doing the same thing as I mentioned, it's centring the top of the div in Safari. I'm looking for a cross browser answer

Comment: @user3550879 Oh, of course. Adding the proper prefixes for this is also key for Safari. Updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Will center vertical `.text-cell`

To center vertical the `<H1>` and `<h3>`, remove the `padding`

**HTML**

```
<article>
 <div class="img-cell">
  <div class="text-cell">
   <div class="extra-css" >
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h3>Category</h3>
   </div>
 </div> 
</div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
 article {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
 }

.img-cell { 
  position: relative;
  height: 375px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

 .text-cell {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   padding: 15px 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   display:table;
    top: 50%; //add this
    display: inline-block; //add this
    transform: translateY(-50%); //add this
    background: #f1f1f1;
    display: inline-block; //add this
    vertical-align: middle; //add this

 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dqe3565c/7/)**

Comment: your fiddle doesn't seem to wrk the way you say. I just need to center the 'text-cell' div since all the titles are in it

Comment: center it relative to what?

Comment: I rebuild the demo..and now you have center vertical and horizontal...now adjust to your needs

Comment: I just need it vertically centred, they won't be horizontally centred. I want it centred relative to 'img-cell' div. It has a set height of 375px. I can use top:30% because it'll make the div look centred, but when the text starts taking up 2+ lines its no longer centred (un-responsive)

Comment: your demo is doing exactly what is happening to me, vertically centring the TOP of the div, not centring the div

Comment: You have to change the html..i rebuild my demo... close your div image at last

Comment: It is still doing what I mentioned. I forgot to mention though that on mobile size screens the 'text-cell' is position:relative and placed below 'img-cell' so I can't close the div outside img-cell